# Update a record by adding data to a single column with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I am new on Laravel 6 and would like to add data to a column. I have a table called 'projects'. This table has a column named 'comments'. My purpose is to only add data to the 'comments' column by updating a project.
I have a ProjectController containing a method storeComment which is as follows:

public function storeComment(Request $request, Project $project)
    {

```
    $validData = $request->validate([
        'project_id'    => 'required',
        'comments'      => 'required'
    ]);


    $project->comments = $validData['comments'];

    $project->save();

    return redirect('home')->with('status', 'Comment created successfully');
}
```

The problem is that the method creates a new record instead of updating an existing one. Is there anybody who could help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function updateComments(Request $request, $id)
{
  $projects = Project::find($id);
  $projects->comments = $request->comments;
  $projects->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the record first, then update comments of that record like this:

```
use App\Project;    

public function storeComment(Request $request) {
   $request->validate([
        'project_id'    => 'required',
        'comments'      => 'required'
    ]);

   $project = Project::find($request->project_id);
   $project->comments = $request->comments;
   $project->save();

   return redirect('home')->with('status', 'Comment created successfully');
}
```

Comment: Welcome Tianma1970